# How to show values in textbox from backend on angular7

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular7 I tried to display values in textbox I'm getting values from backend but I dont know how to display values in textbox can anyone suggest me?

I'm using Loopback and angular7

**file.component.ts**

```
   ngOnInit() {
let userId = window.localStorage.getItem("editUserId");
if(!userId) {
  alert("Invalid action.")
  this.router.navigate(['list-user']);
  return;
}
alert(userId)
this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [''],
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: ['', Validators.required],
  age: ['', Validators.required],
  salary: ['', Validators.required]
});
this.apiService.getUserById(+userId)
  .subscribe( data => {
    this.editForm.setValue(data);
    //alert(data)
  });
}
```

**file.component.html**

```
     <div class="hidden">
  <input type="text" formControlName="id" placeholder="id" name="id" class="form-control" readonly="true">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">User Name:</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" readonly="true">
</div>
```

Comment: If your data is coming back similar format use `this.editForm.patchValue(data)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use set by `this.editForm .controls['firstName'].setValue(data.firstName);`

Another solution you can change `setValue` to `patchValue` method `this.editForm.patchValue(data)`;

Example:

```
 var data= {firstName: 'Hien', lastName : 'Nguyen', email: 'hien@gmail.com'};

 this.editForm .controls['firstName'].setValue(data.firstName);
 this.editForm .controls['lastName'].setValue(data.lastName);
```

Demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-validation-test

Comment: `.value` is readonly, should be using `.setValue(data.firstName)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the input value to the component property. If you can provide a StackBlitz (or other editor), we will be able to help you address specific issues.

```
<div class="hidden">
  <input type="text" formControlName="id" placeholder="id" name="id" class="form-control" readonly="true">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">User Name:</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" readonly="true" [ngModel]="editForm.name">
</div>
```

I recommend [this documentation for more information](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-component-properties-with-interpolation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the patch value API that provided for the form object!

```
this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [''],
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: ['', Validators.required],
  age: ['', Validators.required],
  salary: ['', Validators.required]
});
this.apiService.getUserById(+userId)
  .subscribe( data => {
    this.editForm.patchValue({
         id: data.id,
         name: data.name
         firstName: data.firstName,
         lastName:data.lastName,
         age:data.age,
         salary: data.salary
  });
}
```